# SwiftUI Transition Animation Between Array of Gradients

Tags: swift, animation, swiftui, gradient, linear-gradients

Recently I received some great help here for adding an "EaseIn" animation while cycling through an array of colors using a timer in SwiftUI. It currently works, however, I'm looking to do the same thing but with an 2D array of colors (e.g.,[[Color, Color, Color], [Color, Color, Color]] which are used to create linear gradients in my program. I am using a library called "DynamicColor" to easily create Color variables using a Hex code. I've gotten it cycle through each item in the array and create the gradients; however, the animation is now not working - it just switches to the next gradient without the "EaseIn" animation. The variables that I've created are below:

```
 //Array of gradient colors to cycle through
 //Reference [Top Color, Middle Color, Bottom Color]
 let bgGradientArray:[[UInt64]] = [[0x7E9ACD, 0x7CA0CD, 0x7AA5CD], [0x75AECB, 0x77A9CC, 0x7AA4CC], [0x6DC1C9, 0x74B3CB, 0x7DA1CC], [0x66D4C7, 0x73BBCB, 0x80A0CF], [0x65D8C0, 0x75BDC2, 0x889DC5], [0x6CD1B0, 0x80B3B2, 0x8F99B4], [0x74CAA1, 0x88AEA1, 0x9A93A1], [0x7AC394, 0x91A991, 0xA78D90], [0x83BD85, 0x9BA483, 0xB3887F], [0x88B67A, 0x9FA375, 0xBB8670], [0x97A876, 0xA89475, 0xB98674], [0xA69874, 0xAD9073, 0xB68673], [0xB38973, 0xB38873, 0xB48973], [0xC2786F, 0xBC8271, 0xB48970], [0xD16D6D, 0xC37B6F, 0xB38C72], [0xE05F6B, 0xC8776F, 0xB48B73], [0xDA5B76, 0xC37878, 0xAD917D], [0xCA628A, 0xB67C8B, 0xA2978D], [0xBB6599, 0xAB7F9D, 0x99999E], [0xBB619B, 0xA8859D, 0x999A9E], [0xAC68AF, 0x9D84AF, 0x8FA0B0], [0x9E6EC4, 0x9188C2, 0x83A5C0], [0x9076D1, 0x8690CE, 0x7DA8CB], [0x8886D0, 0x8197CD, 0x7CA7CC], [0x8397CF, 0x7E9ECD, 0x7AA5CD], [0x7BA6CB, 0x7BA6CA, 0x7AA4CC]]
    
 //Initialize the gradient with the item in the array
 @State private var bgGradient = [Color(hex: 0x7E9ACD), Color(hex: 0x7CA0CD), Color(hex: 0x7AA5CD)]
 @State private var bgGradientIndex = 0
    
 //Timer used for cycling through each array item
 @State private var timer = Timer.publish(every: 1, on: .main, in: .common).autoconnect()
```

And below is the ZStack that I've used to implement the animation:

```
ZStack {
            
  //BACKGORUND COLOR TRANSITION ANIMATION
  Rectangle()
     .ignoresSafeArea(.all)
     .foregroundColor(.clear)
     .background(

            //Create linear gradient using the bgGradient variable
            LinearGradient(gradient: Gradient(colors: self.bgGradient), startPoint: .top, endPoint: .bottom)

      )
      .onReceive(timer) { _ in

          //If the index is at the end of the array, restart the timer and make index 0
           if bgGradientIndex == bgGradientArray.count - 1 {

                timer.upstream.connect().cancel()
                        
                DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 1) {
                    withAnimation(.easeIn(duration: 15)) {
                         self.bgGradientIndex = 0
                         self.bgGradient = [Color(hex: UInt64(bgGradientArray[bgGradientIndex][0])), Color(hex: UInt64(bgGradientArray[bgGradientIndex][1])), Color(hex: UInt64(bgGradientArray[bgGradientIndex][2]))]
                                
                    }

                    timer = Timer.publish(every: 1, on: .main, in: .common).autoconnect()
           }
                        
      } else {

          //Add add one to the index and create new linear gradient from this next index
          withAnimation(.easeIn(duration: 15)) {
              self.bgGradientIndex += 1
              self.bgGradient = [Color(hex: UInt64(bgGradientArray[bgGradientIndex][0])), Color(hex: UInt64(bgGradientArray[bgGradientIndex][1])), Color(hex: UInt64(bgGradientArray[bgGradientIndex][2]))]

          }
       }
    }
}
```

Any help on this would be greatly appreciated and I hope I didn't make the question too confusing. Anyways, thanks and hope you all have a great rest of your day!